# "For item in list" loop, need explanation

Tags: python, for-loop

Okay so I have googled this for days now and still just can't grasp the idea of a "for variable in list" loop! I have been doing the Python course by Codecademy and one exercise I did wanted me to print a 5x5 board of "O"s. Now I successfully did it but I still have no idea how! I will give you the code I did and the result.
The code I wrote is:

```
board = []
for i in range(0, 5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)
def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print row
print_board(board)
```

As you can see the goal of the code is to get this result which I did:

```
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
```

Could someone explain to me how the "for row in board" loop and the "for i in range(0, 5)" loop made this outcome? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried reviewing the lesson in Codecademy? I don't suppose they just dumped code at you without explaining it.

Comment: Well they don't really explain it well on Codecademy, they just kind of tell you what to do and then you see the result. I wanted to know how what I did gave the result.

Comment: Maybe you should look for a different course or tutorial, then. Codecademy sounds totally useless.

Comment: Yeah, I have also been dabbling in the non-programmer's tutorial to python, which seems to work better since it shows you how what you are doing does what.

Comment: In my question I stated I googled it repeatedly, I just didn't really grasp it. But ForceBru explained it to me in a way I understand, so this was a last resort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general syntax is `for item in iterator`
That means, that every iteration of the loop, the variables `item` will contain the next item in `iterator`.
For example:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
for number in lst:
   print number #number is 1 then 2 then 3... every iteration its different according to lst

# output:
1
2
3
4
5
```

OK... now `range()` is a really nice function that lets you iterate over numbers easily.
It can get a start, end, step and returns a list of numbers that is all the numbers you asked for. For example `range(1, 11, 2)` will return `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]` (11 **not** included)

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0, 5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)
```

Here you're appending `['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']` (`["0"]` repeated five times) to the list called `board` *five times*. Note that *this whole list* is appended at once, if you append more such lists, `board` will be *a list of lists*, so at each valid index you could find a *list*.

```
for row in board:
    print row
```

This iterates over all the entries of `board`, which, once again, consists *of lists*.

That's why you're getting *five lists* each of which contain *five letters '0'*.

Comment: Thanks ForceBru, I get it now.